# Insert data into mysql table in proper format from java servlet

Tags: java, mysql, regex, string

I am getting cart items and cart price from cart javascript to jsp and then transferring same from jsp to servlet as follows:

```
String a= request.getParameter("cartitems");//but it prints like Jan-2019Feb-2019March-2019

String b=request.getParameter("cartprice");//prints like $100,$200,$400
```

I need to store data in my database as follows:

```
 Cart          Price
Jan-2019        $100
Feb-2019        $200
March-2019      $400
```

I am trying to separate this Jan-2019Feb-2019March-2019 so that it can be stored in my table but unable to do so, Jan-2019Feb-2019March-2019 need not to be separated by date format, it can be separated in any suitable regex if possible.

I tried to separate string a as follows but its not working.

```
     String[] result = a.split(",");
     out.println(Arrays.toString(result));// prints [June-2019March-2019]
```

How can I store datas like above in my databse table, please help ! Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get parameter from your servlet request:

```
String cartItemsParameter= request.getParameter("cartitems");
```

2. use mehod:

```
findRexExpList(cartItemParameter, "\\D+\\d+");
```

method code:

```
 private static List<String> findRexExpList(String text, String regExp) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String group = matcher.group();
        result.add(group);
    }
    return result;
}
```

3. this method return List with separated string
4. For store data:

```
List<String> carts = findRexExpList(cartItemParameter, "\\D+\\d+");
String[] cartPrices = request.getParameter("cartprice").split(",");
for(int i=0; i<cartPrices.length; i++){
   String cart = carts.get(i);
   String price = cartPrices[i];
   //insert cart and price
}
```

Comment: Its showing few errors when I am writing ur code in servlet. Can u please write in more precise way so that I can understand

Comment: findRexExpList("Jan-2019Feb-2019March-2019", "\\D+\\d+"); ---error coming cannot find symbol and here List<String> findRexExpList(text, regExp) { error coming ; expected

Comment: Hi thanks for your help I am almost there, but where can I display output under doPost in Servlet? I am getting error if I write out.println(result); in doPost

Comment: Hi Anton thanks I got the string separated by comma now if I insert this data into my table in mysql then it will be entered as I have mentioned in my question right ?

Comment: How can I remove that square bracket [ ] and only printout Jan-2019, Feb-2019, March-2019 ?

Comment: Square brackets shows because toString() method invoked at ArrayList class. You need to get elements from List.
Or join strings:
`String.join(",", carts);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out ...upvoted and accepted